# Java pattern to change API interface name?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

Is there some sort of pattern/solution I can use to achieve the following:

I am using an API that has an interface called `ApiInterface`.
The interface has 1 method: `void apiMethod(BaseType val);`.

Now, I want to use this functionality but I want to use my own interface, a different method name, and a subtype of `BaseType`:

```
interface MyInterface {
  void myMethod(MyType val); 
}
```

MyType extends BaseType.  `myMethod` should just invoke `apiMethod`, the only difference is that it uses MyType.

Is there a way to create `MyInterface` such that its just a pass through to `ApiInterface` but using a different method name and my own extension of BaseType?  I managed to do this using an abstract class that extends ApiInterface, but I want to use an interface, not a class.

Comment: You can't "expose functionality" in an interface, they have no behaviour, only constants and method contracts.  If you want to provide the implementation (delegation to `ApiInterface`) you need to do that through a class.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Adaptor Design Pattern. It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, an interface does not implement anything. So your ApiInterface should have defined:

```
   void apiMethod(BaseType val);
```

and either there should be some concrete class that implements this method or you have to implement it yourself.

But apart from that, you may need an Adapter.

```
public interface ApiAdapter{
    void myMethod(MyType val);
}

public class ConcreteAdapter implements ApiAdapter{
     void myMethod(MyType val){
         ApiInterface api = new ConcreteApiClass();
         api.apiMethod(val);//should work since MyType extends BaseType
     }
}
```

Now in your code you can declare ConcreteAdapter objects and invoke myMethod using MyType without any reference to ApiInterface etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
public class ApiAdapter implements MyInterface {
  private final ApiInterface delegate;

  public ApiAdapter(ApiInterface delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public void myMethod(MyType value) {
    delegate.apiMethod(value);
  }
}
```

Now if you have code that has a reference to an `ApiInterface` instance and you want to convert that to a `MyInterface` instance you can do something like this:

```
ApiInterface instance = ...;
MyInterface adaptedInstance = new ApiAdapter(instance);
```

Now you can hand off `adaptedInstance` to anyone who needs a `MyInterface`